# CSS responsive grid go from 4 columns to 2

Tags: css, responsive

This is a nicely centered grid, but I want the 4 columns to go down to 2 for mobile. What should I add?

```
body {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  background: grey;
  max-width: 56em;
}

ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 3em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 64em;
}

li {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style: none;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add changes of css when the screen is narrow. Using:

```
@media screen and (max-width: ???px){}
```

And in the block you add rules like in normal css which should change when width of screen is less than given value. I suppose it will be enough for you to deal with this. If you need more information (e.g. new values) write comments and I will try to answer them.

[Examples](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp)

Comment: Hey Tomek - I thought with css grid you did not need media queries? Well I will try it anyway

Comment: In order to change grid values when screen is narrow you have to change this inside media queries. Like here https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=tryresponsive_breakpoints . Here is grid of columns and when screen is below given width, all columns are defined to 100% width.